# Is 'which' a built-in command? Can I override it?

Tags: shell

In openSUSE, the 'which' command actually updates and is very likely to be a separate app, while in some other distro, it is a built-in command.

So if there's a 'which' command in the PATH, will it override the default, built-in one?

Does this apply to the cd command and other built-in commands?

note: https://software.opensuse.org/package/which

Comment: Related (answers part of the question): [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: `which` is a `csh` script from around 1980 that does not make sense with with Bourne Shell compatible shells, in special as it bases alias recognition on `~/.cshrc`.

Comment: @schily No, that may have been the way it started, but now it is no longer the case. The which from Debian doesn't read (nor it try) any alias file. It is a quite simple shell script to walk the path and print the first match (sometimes all).

Comment: @Isaac No, your claim may be true on Linux but is not true in general. `file /usr/bin/which` -> `executable /usr/bin/csh script`

Comment: @schily I never meant to say that is was "in general" for everyone and everywhere. I just gave a particular example of a correct implementation that others should copy IMO. Also, your claim is not true "in general" as (at least) Debian doesn't follow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many questions. Lets try to answer them:

### Is 'which' a built-in command?

Yes

- A builtin in some shells (csh, tcsh and zsh),
- A tracked alias (what the shell prints on `type which` for a hashed command (read about `hash`)) in (lksh, mksh, ksh93, and attsh) and
- An external app in (dash, bash, yash).

So, there is not a general simple answer.

### Can I override it?

Always, the order of execution is alias, special built-in, (and, after searching in the PATH) function, regular builtin, and external utility.

To override:

- an special builtin use an alias,
- a regular builtin (what which should be) use either an alias or a function.
- And, if the PATH is used, you can always add an executable ahead of others.
- Also, some shells may provide additional controls of builtins, like (%builtin) in path search of [Minix I (1989) ash shell](https://minix1.woodhull.com/current/2.0.2/wwwman/man1/ash.1.html) or [enable/disable in ksh, bash, zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29638175/8017719)

### In openSUSE, Is the 'which' command a separate app?

Yes, as is also in Fedora, Debian and many others. But still, shells may have their particular say in this.

### Is it a built-in command in other distros ?

That depends more on what shell you use than on what a distro decides to have as available files. A distro selects files, a shell selects builtins.

### Will a 'which' command in the PATH override the default, built-in one?

No, as an app is the last executed element in the execution search sequence.

### Does this also apply to the cd command and other built-in commands?

A `cd` is an **regular** builtin, as such it could be override by an alias or a function (in Posix terms: only if an executable of the same name exists in the PATH).

Comment: *tracked alias* just means it's been added to the hash table of external commands in ksh (see the `hash` builtin/alias). You'll get that for every external command.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and I am aware of that. But, in simple terms for people learning about this area, that is exactly what the command reports ("which is a tracked alias for ..."). It seems simpler to report exactly what the shell prints than to get into the exact details (and complexities) of what a "tracked alias" is or means. But still, if you wish to write about it: you may still ask a separate question.

Comment: For completeness, in the Almquist shell (still the case on some of its derivatives), you can have external builtins take precedence over builtins if you put their directory ahead of the `%builtin` special value in `$PATH`. For some of ksh93's builtin, same with the `/opt/ast/bin` special value. ksh93, bash, zsh can enable/disable builtins individually as well (with the `builtin`, `enable`, `disable` or `zmodload` builtins depending on the shell).

Comment: Oh, sure, **(1)** the [Minix **I** (1987) ash](https://minix1.woodhull.com/current/2.0.2/wwwman/man1/ash.1.html) used a `%builtin` and a `%func` in the path search. Many present day implementations of `ash` ([present linux ash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash) and [present day netbsd's ash](https://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sh+1.i386+NetBSD-9.0) doesn't do that anymore. Probably it was a bad idea. And **(2)** Yes, there are enable and disable commands in ksh, bash, zsh to enable/disable specific builtins. But Please!: don't drive this to **The trees don't let you see the forest** post.

Comment: Minix initially used the Forsyth shell. ash was first released in 1989. `dash` still honours `%builtin` even if it doesn't document it its man page, some BSDs and busybox have removed/disabled it. I added that as a note in a comment to your answer *for completeness*. I still upvoted your answer.

Comment: And I am **trying** to incorporate your comments somewhere without flooding the answer in details. Cut me some slack, will you? @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Tbh I never thought that this is shell-dependent. I think this is the right answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

`which` is a built-in in zsh, but not in most other shells.  If you are using zsh and invoke `which`, it will use the shell built-in, which is the typical behavior when a command and a shell built-in share the same name.

If you want to invoke the command, then POSIX provides the `command` builtin to do that: `command which`.  If you want to know where a command is located, the POSIX way to do that is `command -v`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110117/discussion-between-isaac-and-stephane-chazelas).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to find out using `which`:

On Fedora 32:

```bsh
$ which which
alias which='(alias; declare -f) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot'
    /usr/bin/which

$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/which
which-2.21-19.fc32.x86_64
```

So, a separate command.

Comment: In a Bourne-like shell, you'd rather use `type which`. `which` can report the wrong thing in a wide variety of corner cases.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It much depends on the specific which that you are using. Yes, some shell's which may get the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
$ help
 alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]          logout [n]
 bg [job_spec ...]                       mapfile [-d delim] [-n count] [-O or>
 bind [-lpsvPSVX] [-m keymap] [-f file>  popd [-n] [+N | -N]
 break [n]                               printf [-v var] format [arguments]
 builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]       pushd [-n] [+N | -N | dir]
 caller [expr]                           pwd [-LP]
 case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...)>  read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [->
 cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]            readarray [-d delim] [-n count] [-O >
 command [-pVv] command [arg ...]        readonly [-aAf] [name[=value] ...] o>
 compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option] [>  return [n]
 complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DEI]>  select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMM>
 compopt [-o|+o option] [-DEI] [name .>  set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option->
 continue [n]                            shift [n]
 coproc [NAME] command [redirections]    shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]
 declare [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] [name[=v>  source filename [arguments]
 dirs [-clpv] [+N] [-N]                  suspend [-f]
 disown [-h] [-ar] [jobspec ... | pid >  test [expr]
 echo [-neE] [arg ...]                   time [-p] pipeline
 enable [-a] [-dnps] [-f filename] [na>  times
 eval [arg ...]                          trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
 exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [argume>  true
 exit [n]                                type [-afptP] name [name ...]
 export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or ex>  typeset [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] name[=v>
 false                                   ulimit [-SHabcdefiklmnpqrstuvxPT] [l>
 fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last] o>  umask [-p] [-S] [mode]
 fg [job_spec]                           unalias [-a] name [name ...]
 for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMAND>  unset [-f] [-v] [-n] [name ...]
 for (( exp1; exp2; exp3 )); do COMMAN>  until COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
 function name { COMMANDS ; } or name >  variables - Names and meanings of so>
 getopts optstring name [arg]            wait [-fn] [id ...]
 hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name >  while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
 help [-dms] [pattern ...]               { COMMANDS ; }
root@machinexa:~# help | grep which
root@machinexa:~#
```

Which is not a bash builtin ? Comment if i am wrong
Also to view the path do `env $PATH`, you could also check for which in every path like `ls /usr/bin/which` where /usr/bin is replaced by all paths

Comment: The OP does not restrict the question to `bash`; it is tagged (at present) only `shell`.